# Как добавить pdb в пакет nuget для дальнейшей отладки?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget

Есть проект, который используется другими проектами. Подключается через nuget. Мне необходима возможность отладки с доступом к символам этого пакета.

Что я делал:

Создал пакет командой

```
dotnet pack --include-source --include-symbols -c Release
```

находясь в папке с проектом.

В итоге создалось 2 файла: ???.nupkg и ???.source.nupkg

Первый, соответственно, без pdb, второй с pdb (открыв второй файл блокнотом, обнаружил там среди бинарной неразберихи текстовую информацию. В том числе там были файла ???.dll и ???.pdb

Залил пакет на nuget.org, дождался его появления, подключил пакет к другому проекту, запустил в отладке. В итоге я попал в исходники нугетовского проекта, но, наведя на открывшийся в студии файл я увидел путь к нему. Он находится в той папке, где я собирал этот пакет. Короче студия сослалась на локальный проект, а файл pdb вместе с dll не подтянулся. Короче, когда я нугетовский проект переместил (переименовал), студия не смогла зайти в исходники этого проекта во время отладки.

Помогите, а то сейчас для отладки проектов, которые тянут проекты с нугет (наши, конечно же, проекты, не сторонние, с нашего репозитория) приходится удалять референсы на пакеты и подгружать нужные проекты напрямую.

Comment: Под эту задачу я писал расширение под VS17, которое автоматизирует переключение ссылок с пакетов на проект и обратно. Чуть позже скину.

Comment: @UserName, это, здорово, плюсик поставлю, но сразу говорю, за ответ это не сойдет. Вопрос тут все же в другом

Comment: Спустя несколько лет вспомнил.. [NuGetSwitcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=github0UserName.DCB9FB28-5610-4A94-9471-4BF2D0556BC5)